# Capturing a stream of vector data and visualizing it on the Nexus tablet

Tags: android, c++, stream

Desperately need help!

The problem is as follows: there is a bunch of medical diagnostic devices packed in a box. They are all fed from the same battery, and their data is supposed to be visualized on a Nexus tablet, also enclosed in the box. Only one device at a time is connected to a tablet. Connection is via USB port, processing off-line only. Data is streaming in real-time (some devices may have recording capability, some don't) and needs to be visualized in real-time also.

The devices are "dumb" and there are no SDKs. Seemingly, the devices were never intended to be connected to any external visualizer or any other device. All we have to work with is the raw stream of data - the output of a device is not even a file but a stream of 256 vectors. This stream needs to be captured, written to a predefined buffer/series of buffers (how to determine size of such buffer to be generic enough to satisfy every device in the box?), and then translated into some format that Android tablet can visualize.

Is my understanding of the required architecture correct? What language shall this software be written in? can it be done in something truly cross-platform like Python? Does there exist any open-source functionality for capturing a stream (if so, please, kindly recommend)? Is it possible to have such a software generic so that changing a device/tablet/OS could be accommodated without an excruciating pain?